# ExtJs IconCls not working in ToolBar

Tags: css, extjs, grid, icons, toolbar

Icons aren't displaying on my gridPanel's toolbar - only the text is being displayed.

Is there a specific css class I should be using? I tried using button.print and just .print but neither work.

```
,tbar: [
{
     text   : 'Print',
     iconCls: 'print',
     handler: function() {
         Ext.ux.Printer.BaseRenderer.prototype.stylesheetPath = 'css/DETR_WEB.print.css';
         var grid = Ext.getCmp("outstandingGrid");
         alert(grid.title);
         Ext.ux.Printer.print(grid);
    }
}]

.print{
    background-image: url(../images/print.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

Comment: Have you checked which css-attributes are set on the button, eg. using FireBug or similar?

Comment: there's x-toolbar-cell and x-btn-bml but when I apply either, it adds the space for the icon but not the actual icon. I removed the background repeat css property but it had no effect

Comment: Check that your style is not down-prioritised by another style. If this is the case, try changing to `background-image: url(../images/print.png) !important;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem once, and I found out that a style in Ext is overriding my image. So when dealing with toolbars I always add the `!important` to the `background-image`:

```
background-image: url(../images/print.png) !important;
```

*I have added this answer to clarify that the question has been answered with a solution that seems to help the OP.*

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues when specifying an iconCls with a background-image that the image was appearing for the first level menu items but not for the submenu items. I confirm that adding the !important after the background-iamge definition solved this issue.